# using nfcpy and spi to connect PN532 to Rasperry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc

I have a PN532 NFC reader from sunfounder and a pi B3 and can't get nfcpy to work with it.

The reader itself is connected correctly: I used libnfc to test and it is working completely fine and NFC tags are recognised perfectly. Listing the PN532 through spi works as well: `ls /dev/spi*` leaves `/dev/spidev0.0  /dev/spidev0.1`

But since I am more comfortable using python I'd love to use python.

From the [docs](http://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clf.html#module-nfc.clf.pn532) of nfcpy I know spi is somehow supported.

But when trying to connect with nfcpy it seems to search infinitely for a device. As described in the [docs](http://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html), I tried to connect to the PN532:

```
import nfs
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()
assert clf.open('tty:AMA0:pn532') is True
```

I tried various different inputs instead of 'tty:AMA0:pn532' but none work.

If anybody has an idea to read some uids from nfc tags in this setup I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting a reader through SPI is currently not supported by nfcpy. Your connectivity options are either the serial port on GPIO or a USB-Serial adapter (FTDI). Note that for RPi 3 the serial port is only capable running at 116.2 kbps because (The faster port is used for Bluetooth but it is possible to switch them).

Comment: but UART or I2C as a connection should work perfectly fine or is there another part missing?

Comment: Only UART and USB via FTDI. SPI and I2C are not yet supported.